# feign client multipart/form-data POST request giving 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, post, openfeign

I am trying to raise a feign client post request where I need to pass a JSON (multi-line text) and not a file. I am passing the content-type as multipart/form-data. And in my method, I am passing a POJO (containing all the fields that will be in the JSON) with @RequestPart annotation. And my builder has a SpringFormEncoder. But I am getting a 400 Bad Request in response. Can you please let me know what am I doing wrong here?
Feign Client -

```
@RequestLine("POST /test")
@Headers({"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"})
void testmethod(@RequestPart(value="name") MyObject myobj);
```

Builder -

```
@Bean
public Encoder feignEncoder(){
 return new SpringFormEncoder(new SpringEncoder(this.messageConverters));
}
```

And I want the json to be sent in this format -
{
"firstField": "field value",
"secondField": "second value
}

Comment: I request that you post some code to go along with your question, please.

Comment: @Alias Cartellano I just added some of the code. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem when sending json type of payload as form-data content-type. My solution was to use `JsonFormWriter`. On your feign configuration class, add this:

```java
@Bean
public JsonFormWriter jsonFormWriter() {
   return JsonFormWriter()
}
```

This might also help: [Feign multipart with Json request part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070641/feign-multipart-with-json-request-part)