# Sending Map with Feign Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I am trying to send request with Feign client, my request includes Map<String, String>. While sending request, Feign client throws an exception. An exception is:

> class java.util.LinkedHashMap is not a type supported by this encoder.

Detail exception message is;

[image: Detailed exception.]

There is my request class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class DocumentRequest extends BaseExternalRequest {
    private Map<String, String> metaData;
    private String documentTypeId;
}
```

And this is consumer request model;

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class DocumentRequest extends BaseExternalRequest {
    private Map<String, String> metaData;
    private String documentTypeId;
}
```

Cleint Controller endpoint:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<String>> uploadDocument(@RequestPart("request") DocumentRequest request, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    request = dysBaseRequestUtil.fillDysBaseRequest(request);
    return dysDocumentClient.uploadDocument(request);
}
```

Feign Client interface;

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<String>> uploadDocument(@RequestPart DocumentRequest request);
```

Consumer controller;

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
@RestDMSLogger(code = EndpointCodeConstants.UPLOAD_DOCUMENT)
public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<String>> uploadDocument(@RequestPart DocumentRequest request) {
    String insertedEntityId = documentService.uploadDocument(documentMapper.documentRequestToDocumentDto(request));
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new BaseResponse<>(insertedEntityId));
}
```

How can I get rid of this exception.

Comment: Anastasiia Smirnova's answer solved my issue. Thanks Anastasiia Smirnova :). Link is; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63070641/feign-multipart-with-json-request-part